# Why is my VueJS Login reloading despite catch being called?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code. The catch() is getting called, I can see the toastr alert. However immediately after the page reloads. Any idea why?

```
signIn() {
    this.$store
    .dispatch('auth/login', this.credentials)
    .then(() => {
            this.$toastr.s('You are successfully logged in')
            this.$router.push({ name: 'About' })

    })
    .catch(() => {
        // this.$toastr.e('You are successfully logged in')
      this.$toastr.e('Please check the form')

    })
}
```

Login Code:

```
login({ commit }, data) {
    commit(types.AUTH_ERROR_CHANGE, null)
    // console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL);
    const url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/authentication_token'

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
      .post(url, data)
      .then(response => {
        commit(types.AUTH_UPDATE_TOKEN, response.data)
        resolve(state)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        commit(types.AUTH_ERROR_CHANGE, 'Incorrect username or password')
        reject(state)
      })
    })
  },``
```

Comment: Can you share your vuex login action code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, the problem was elsewhere completely.

I had an axios interceptor from previous code:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  data => {
    store.commit('general/' + types.LOADING_STOP)

    return data
  },
  error => {
    store.commit('general/' + types.LOADING_STOP)

    if (
      error.response &&
      error.response.status &&
      error.response.status === 401
    ) {
     // window.location.href = '/login'
    }

    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
```

I had an old location.href there